# Android studio - cannot change theme

Tags: android-studio

I don't know what happened but I cannot change themes for android studio. Theme button is greyed out.

[image]

Comment: have u tried changed theme from Setting -> Theme yet?

Comment: try to use plugin Material Theme UI & Atom Material Icons, they have much beautiful things :)

Comment: @DươngThái thanks for the input, turned out I was forcing android studio to sync theme with my OS after the update.

Comment: @Nikhil You should update this question by posting your answer and accepting it as the solution to know that it is now resolved.